# Is iMovie available on the MacBook Air 11 inch?

Tags: macbook-pro, imovie

Is iMovie available on the MacBook Air 11 inch? The iMovie system requirements say that the minimum resolution is 1280x800, while the 11 inch Air has 1366x768.

Comment: Yes. iMovies works perfectly fine on the MacBook Air 11 inch.

Answer (score 1):

It will run. It should even be [pre-installed](https://www.apple.com/macbook-air/built-in-apps.html). Might not be the best user experience, though, with limited window size. Get as much RAM as you can afford.